# Find the density function of a random vector $w = (X_{(3)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(1)})$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let a random vector $v = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ be given, the components of which are independent and uniformly distributed on the segment $[1, 5]$. Find the density function of a random vector $w = (X_{(3)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(1)})$ consisting of components of the vector $v$ ordered in non-increasing order.

The only thing I came up with was to find the distribution $F_w(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, which should be equal $P(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2,X_3\leq x_3|X_1\leq X_2\leq X_3)$

Comment: Have a look at any book introducing order statistics.